# Add css with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image]

I want to have access to the login.css file. For that I try to do this in the login page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..static/css/login.css" th:href="@{/static/css/login.css}"/>
```

And I have a WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring-Boot?

Comment: Yes, I use Spring Boot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use Spring-Boot, the path should be recognized automatically. The project structure should be alike:

- `resources/static/js`
- `resources/static/css`

In case there are no other overridden methods, remove the `WebConfig` class with the annotations. I recommend avoiding using the `@EnableWebMvc` with Spring-Boot since you take all the control (and responsibility) over the MVC configuration.

Access to a static resource with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/login.css}"/>
```

Comment: I did how you told me, but when I try to access the login page, it appears without css style. After authentication I receive http://localhost:8082/css/login.css, that contains the code from login.css and if I click back I receive the form with css included.

Comment: I succed after I added more:  antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()